# jcrollpane or scroll fpr overflow-y and make the content stays at panel bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane

I hope the subject line makes sense.

I am working on a live chat support area. The chat area is 300px in height, I am having a problem, when the chat message is longer than 300px, while the vertical scroller shows up it always stay at the top each time when a message is entered either by customer or operator.

I am not particular interested in using js if I can get it done with simple CSS. The closer example  I could find is jscrollpane which shows an automatic reinitialisation example, but the the result I see is exactly the same as with the simple overflow-y that I have.
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html
I wonder if it's not possible to make the  make the content stays at panel bottom (bottom part of the container)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough version of jScrollPane there is a `stickToBottom` setting you can pass in. This will ensure that the jScrollPane sticks to the bottom when new content is added (but only if the scrollpane has already been scrolled to the bottom - otherwise there would never be any way to scroll anywhere else).

I put together a demo of it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/F9EsN/

Comment: Hi Vitch,
Thanks for the demo!